# What is the namespace i need to use to declare a particular class? 

Tags: .net, c++-cli

The class is the following:

```
public __gc class test :public MarshalByValueComponent,IListSource,ISupportInitialize,ISerializable
```

Comment: Did you get this off a stack trace or something?

Comment: you technically don't need to have your class in any namespace

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is `System.ComponentModel`